# Find a minimum value which satisfies an equation

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, assumptions, inequalities

I have to find a minimum value of "a" which makes x=-a+b+c, y=-a+b+c^2 positive where a>1, 0

```
$Assumptions = {a > 1, b > 0, c > 0}
x = -a + b + c
y = -a + b + c^2 
Reduce[{x > 0, y > 0}, a]
```

and it gives

```
b \[Element] Reals && ((c <= 0 && a < b + c) || (0 < c <= 1 &&a < b + c^2) || (c > 1 && a < b + c))
```

but I want to have numerical value of a, e.g. a=1.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no such a.

Comment: With the current constraints there is an infinite number of solutions for a, and this is given by the output. You might try FindInstance if you want to have an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
RegionPlot3D[-a + b + c > 0 && -a + b + c^2 > 0 && a > 1 && b > 0 &&  c > 0, 
            {a, -10, 20}, {b, -10, 10}, {c, -10, 10}, 
            AxesLabel -> {a, b, c}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]